# Is it a must that the selector tag defined in the bootstrapping component to be used in index.html?

Tags: angular

I have created a basic Angular 2 app. In the `app.module.ts` , the bootstrap component is in `app.component.ts` with `<app>` as the selector tag.
 
When I use any other tag instead of `<app>`, the console window gives an error -

> The selector "app" did not match any elements.

**Is it a must that the selector tag mentioned in the bootstrap component should be used in the index.html file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

That's the bootstrapped component selector check app.component.ts `selector: 'app'`

That selector is where Angular2 is bootstrapped too.

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-name',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

index.html

```
<app-name></app-name>
```

It has to match the selector for bootstrapping to work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So that means all other selector tags should be used inside this <app> tag in app.component.html i.e no other tags in index.html ?

Comment: When Angular renders the component it will remove anything that's between the start and closing tag. You should only put content inside a component selector if you use the <ng-content></ng-content> inside the component template. I can show you an example if you like because that might be confusing.

Comment: ``<ng-content>` is not supported in the root component though.